# Load url from Activity1 to Activity2 which contains a webview

Tags: c#, android, url, webview, xamarin

How do I load a url from firstActivity to the webpageActivity? 
I would like to be able to click a button with the url from firstActivity then pass it to the webpage activity and load the url.

Here is my code: FirstActivity

protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

```
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it


        var scisnews = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.scisnewsbtn);
        string scisnewsurl = "http://cis.ulster.ac.uk/news-a-events-mainmenu-70";


        //labinduction.Click += (sender, e) => {
        //  var LabInductionI = new Intent (this, typeof(LabInduction));
        //  StartActivity (LabInductionI);
        //};

        scisnews.Click += delegate {
            var ScisNewsI = new Intent (this, typeof(WebPage));
            ScisNewsI.PutExtra ("scisnews", scisnewsurl);
            this.StartActivity (ScisNewsI);
        };
    }

        public class HelloWebViewClient : WebViewClient
        {
            public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, string url)
            {
            view.LoadUrl ("http://cis.ulster.ac.uk/news-a-events-mainmenu-70");
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
```

Code: WebPageActivity

```
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Create your application here
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.WebPageLO);

        web_view = FindViewById<WebView> (Resource.Id.webview);

        web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        web_view.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;




        web_view.SetWebViewClient (new HelloWebViewClient ());



    }
}


public class HelloWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, string url)
    {
        view.LoadUrl ("http://cis.ulster.ac.uk/news-a-events-mainmenu-70");
        return true;
    }
}


public override bool OnKeyDown (Android.Views.Keycode keyCode, Android.Views.KeyEvent e)
{
    if (keyCode == Keycode.Back && web_view.CanGoBack ()) 
    {
        web_view.GoBack ();
        return true;
    }

    return base.OnKeyDown (keyCode, e);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally pass information from one activity to another by using the `Intent` class. It looks like you are trying to, but don't have the code pulling the value out.

Here is an example:

```
//In your first activity
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(WebPage));
intent.PutExtra("url", "http://cis.ulster.ac.uk/news-a-events-mainmenu-70");
StartActivity(intent);

//Then in the second activity
string url = Intent.GetStringExtra("url");

//Then you can load the page like this
web_view.LoadUrl(url);
```

Does this help?

Comment: My next question is how could i override this so that if another button is clicked, say i add another url from the first activity, i want it to load a different url but in the same webpage activity?

e.g.
'var intent2 = new Intent (this, typeof(WebPage));
intent.PutExtra("url2", "google.com");
StartActivity(intent2);'

what will i do for the second activity then?